# Turn off real-time code analysis in Eclipse (PyDev)

Tags: eclipse, pydev

First of all, I hope I didn't just use the wrong keywords for my simple question during my fruitless search for answers on the web.

I'm using Eclipse with PyDev. There is the code analysis option in the Editor menu that has the following three options (among many others): I want to *use it* (true) *only on saving* a file (true), not *on every successful parse* (false).

Checking these options changes nothing in my case. Did I miss other options or conditions somewhere? Obviously there's no use for me in knowing that a single `if` is invalid syntax while I'm literally typing the condition.

That, for one, is annoying, but it also interferes with the highlighting of occurrencies. If I want to see all occurrencies of variable `x`, Eclipse will only highlight occurrencies up to its surmised syntax error (the line I'm typing). Especially when refactoring older code, I want to check back which variables are where when I add a new function/-ality.

Thanks!

Comment: Just added some more explanation. No one's got an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Humm, for code analysis the 'only on save' should work (in PyDev > Editor > Code Analysis).

Now, what I think you're talking about is the syntax validation... and there's really no option to disable it (regarding the highlighting, as the highlighting needs a proper AST, which is generated along the syntax validation, disabling the syntax validation wouldn't help there).

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know there was a difference between the two. I just went by the PyDev menu. Seems that all one can do is remove the text markings, without removing the side-effect on things like occurrencies highlighting. If there are no further comments/solutions, I'll mark this as the answer. And maybe consider a lighter tool for python development.

Comment: Actually, if you don't see value in the code analysis or indexing, you can disable the builders altogether or just the parser notifications (in preferences > pydev > builders)

Comment: Ah, thanks! This comes closest to what I was looking for. I can change the parsing interval to a more relaxed cycle of, say, 6000ms (was 3000 by default). That way, I still have a chance of typing that condition before the alarm goes ;)